# Python - Making arguments to a function optional

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing

I am learning to build a Python function that takes some inputs from the user and passes it to the function to execute as part of a SQL statement.

```
def sales(sale_date,prod_type,prod_category):
    db.execute("""select prod_name,quantity,price_per_product from sales 
                      where sale_date = (%s) and prod_type = (%s) and prod_category =(%s)""",
                      (sale_date,prod_type,prod_category)
```

I am wondering how could I modify the above function such that if one of the arguments are not provided I would still execute the function but however the missing argument would not be added as filters.

That is if sale_date is Null (or None), how could I modify the above function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about using default arguments and handling the cases individually? Take a look at this snippet:

```
def sales(sale_date=None, prod_type=None, prod_category=None):

    if sale_date is not None and prod_type is not None and prod_category is not None:
        db.execute("""select prod_name,quantity,price_per_product from sales 
                      where sale_date = (%s) and prod_type = (%s) and prod_category =(%s)""",
                      (sale_date,prod_type,prod_category)
    # Handling other cases
    elif ... :
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

You could provide a separate SQL statement for every case you want to cover.